# Should I Expect Reimbursement for a 2 Year Old Furnace?

Tags: furnace

I'm having an addition put onto my home and it is significant enough to warrant a larger furnace.

Unfortunately, I recently had to replace my furnace. It is a two years old Trane brand furnace, two stage high efficency (96.7). It is relatively small, but it was still roughly 4k to purchase.

Am I crazy to think that the heating and cooling guys would be able to reuse or otherwise resell it?

I'm not necessarily expecting even 50% of the original cost...

Comment: -1 because I believe this gets into pricing and contractor negotiations.

Comment: Is the ductwork way oversized to begin with? because if not it's about to be undersized. +1 at Ecnerwal's second system solutions, however radiant heat can't cool.

Comment: I thought about that, noted that the question did not mention AC or cooling other than "heating and cooling guys" and proceeded along heat only lines. And yep, going to need new ductwork to support this.

Comment: So, the air conditioner supposedly was somewhat oversized for what I had. The heater was recently done and the "right" size from what I was told. And, sorry, I should have pointed out that the ducts are going to be resized. So, I take issue with the downvote -- I don't even know/understand whether these systems can be reused elsewhere, so I'm asking whether or not it is reasonable to negotiate some type of dollar amount with regards to the unit. Obviously, I'd rather let the HVAC people deal with it in general (whether they sold it or me)

Comment: what does this question have to do with home improvement as defined here? it's a very nice question, very well framed and all, and i understand that you do have a serious query, but really? this isn't the place for such a question. i don't know which other place is, but this isn't it.

Comment: Perhaps angie's list would have been a better place or something along those lines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resell it yourself, rather than having the HVAC folks take it away. Put it on craigslist, etc. If you have them take it away, they will almost certainly sell or use it, but you getting any money from that would be more difficult to arrange; you can ask them, rather than us, about that.

You can add a second furnace only big enough for the new addition, and run both. In some cases, depending on setup, this can be more efficient than one large one, as you can run only the smaller one until the load is too much for it, switch to the bigger one as the load increases, and run both only when maximum heating effort is required.

The simpler approach  (with no efficiency advantage) is just to separate the two systems, so the one you have now heats the house you have now, and the new one heats only the addition. Rather than losing a pile of money on the one you have, you just buy a smaller one for the new part. Depending on what extent the new furnace price is related to size, this may not make sense - then again, you might be able to find one on craigslist (et al) yourself...

A curveball approach would be to look at a different method for heating the new addition - a water heater to run radiant floors/walls may cost a good deal less than a furnace, and radiant is easy to build in.